# How to change permalinks to taxonomy and post type's posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

Hello I want to change my taxonomies and posts permalink.
I have taxonomies like that;

> - Audi
> - - A1
> - - - 1.4 TFSI
> - - - 1.6 TDI
> - - A3
> - - - 1.2
> - - - 1.4
> - - - 1.6
> - BMW
> - - 1 series
> - - - 115d
> - - - 116d
> - - 2 series
> - - - 220d

Question 1 )
How Can I change permalink for **taxonomy** as

> - site.com/brand/audi
> - site.com/brand/audi/a1
> - site.com/brand/audi/a1/14-tfsi
> - site.com/brand/audi/a1/16-tdi
> - site.com/brand/bmw
> - site.com/brand/bmw/1-series
> - site.com/brand/bmw/1-series/115d

Question 2 )
How Can I change permalink for **posts**

> - site.com/bmw/1-series/115d/post-title
> - site.com/audi/a1/16-tdi/post-title

This is Code What I use;

```
## Auto Post Type
function autoCats() {
## Brand - Model - Version
register_taxonomy(
'brand',
'auto',
array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'label'             => 'Marka / Model / Versiyon',
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array(
            'slug'          => 'marka',
            'with_front'    => false
    )
)
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'autoCats', 0 );

function autoRegister() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Araç', 'catchthemes_custom_post','catchthemes' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Araç', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Araç Ekle', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Yeni Bir Araç Ekle', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Aracı Düzenleyin', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'Yeni Araç', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'Aracı Önizleyin', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Araç Ara', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'Henüz Araç Eklenmemiş', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Çöp Kutusunda Birşey Bulunamadı', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent ThemePost:', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Araçlar', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
);

$args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'Araç',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'comments', 'custom-fields' ),
        'taxonomies' => array('brand', 'post_tag', 'auto_cat'), // this is IMPORTANT
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/iconAuto.png',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        //'rewrite' => true <-- this is what you need!
        //'rewrite' => array('slug' => '%auto_cat%/%brand%','with_front' => false),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => 'auto',
        'capability_type' => 'post'
);
register_post_type( 'auto', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'autoRegister', 20 );
```

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to register your taxonomy?

Comment: I've just added

Answer (score 0):

Go to the permalinks setting in the wordpress settings page and change the permalink structure to this.

```
 https://mysite.com/%category%/%postname%/
```

And now add this code in your .htaccess file to achieve that permalink structure.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```